# Plesk RCP API Subdomain with different home

Tags: api, rcp, plesk

Like described in the docs.. 
http://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/PP10/10.2.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=53497.htm

It should be possible to change the home-location of a subdomain with the "home" Parameter. So, i tried to put values in home like "/" or "/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/httpdocs" or even letting empty (somewhere it was described like that)..

But, in every case, the "httpd.include" File is having a normal path for the subdomain like i create it on the plesk-gui afterwards, that sucks :(

Does anybody know why the "change" of the home-directory is just not working through the RCP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you have to update Plesk to the latest version 10 - only in this version it is possible to make a subdomain that is pointing on a different folder than the default behavior would (and just speaking for the api here)